# Windows 8.1 shows activated in computer property, but i encounter message saying 'windows will expire soon'

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-activation

I have got my Lenovo Z50-70 about one month ago with Windows 8.1 Installed. It keeps flashing the message 'Your Windows will expire soon'

[image: ttp://divyashah.in/windows_issue/Expire.png]

But when I check activation status it shows me its activated in Computer properties.

[image: http://divyashah.in/windows_issue/activated.png]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Call Lenovo support. Apple has never used software piracy protection, and ever since Windows adopted it starting with XP, it has become worse with each new OS they spit out, i feel for you.

Comment: Run CMD as admin and use `SLMGR.VBS -XPR` and check the expiry status of Windows

Comment: I already did it, it gives me this [Image : Expiry Status](http://divyashah.in/windows_issue/cmd.png)

Comment: Did your machine come with Windows 8 and you upgraded it to Windows 8.1?

Comment: No it was already 8.1

Comment: as I said in the SO topic, run **slmgr.vbs -dlv** and post the output.

Comment: where is the output of *slmgr.vbs -dlv*?

Comment: Output of slmgr.vbs -dlv [Output](http://divyashah.in/windows_issue/output.png)

Comment: next time, please post a @ and my username so that I get notified when you reply to me.

Answer (score 4):

The slmgr output

[image]

shows me that your laptop was activated via KMS, which doesn't apply to Core (Single Language) Editions, only Pro or Enterprise and the Embedded Editions.

Contact the seller of the Lenovo device why he sells devices with KMS activation (likely pirated).

Comment: have you got an answer from the seller why he sold a KMS activated edition?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure this'll work, but you can try extracting your product key from the BIOS using [RWEverything](http://rweverything.com) or [Windows 9 Product Key Viewer](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/30363-Windows-9-Product-Key-Viewer).

You may then enter that key when Windows prompts you to activate your copy or you could manually bring up the activation window by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>→`slui 3`→<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[Or](http://ss64.com/nt/slmgr.html) you could enter the key from the command prompt:

```
SLUI.exe 3 XXXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXX
```

This seems to happen when malware or some other program modifies your product key so better scan your computer for malware using [Malwarebytes Anti-malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org) before you attempt this.

### With RWEverything:

[image: RWEverything]

### With Windows 9 Product Key Viewer:

[image: Windows 9 Product Key Viewer]

Answer (score 1):

I bought a ASUS N551Z installed with Windows 8.1 Single Language, and it was ok at the beginning after first activation success and it stay normal for couple month. Only recently it start prompting me activate Windows, the sad thing is the windows status still "activated" and even after I try to press the activate button again it didn't do anything but keep prompting me for activation after several minutes,

I called the sales person and they told me that to fix it i should restore the machine due to a BUG to resolve the issue and that means I had to reinstall, setup the computer again.  Bear in mind if you use ASUS Backtracker that means it will wipe the entire HDD all over again.

Comment: This is in danger of looking like a forum thread. Consider rewording your answer to be more generally applicable, instead of anecdotal.